# Clarification on the comparison between regression lines

Tags: r, regression, anova

I have this dataframe:

```
Help_df<- data.frame(
  Variety=c('Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL', 
            'Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL',
            'Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL',
            'Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL', 'Sirio CL', 'Augusto', 
            'Augusto', 'Augusto', 'Augusto', 'Augusto', 'Augusto', 
            'Augusto', 'Augusto', 'Augusto', 'Augusto', 'Augusto',
            'Augusto', 'Augusto', 'Augusto', 'Augusto', 'Mare CL', 
            'Mare CL', 'Mare CL', 'Mare CL', 'Mare CL', 'Mare CL',
            'Mare CL', 'Mare CL', 'Mare CL', 'Mare CL', 'Mare CL', 
            'Mare CL', 'Mare CL', 'Mare CL', 'Mare CL'),
  Yield=c(6.98, 6.41, 6.73, 7.15, 7.32, 6.55, 6.92, 7.12, 
          6.77, 6.38, 6.4, 6.1, 5.9, 5.5, 5.6, 6.66, 6.51,
          6.15, 6.03, 6.21, 6.8, 5.98, 6.52, 6.25, 5.56,
          5.9, 5.39, 4.9, 5.6, 5, 4.25, 4.65, 4.89, 4.656,
          5.32, 5.69, 5.89, 6.02, 6.32, 6.54, 6.65, 6.54,
          6.87, 7.2, 6.21 ),
  Index=c(333, 328, 271, 265, 281, 272, 337, 389, 276, 296, 250, 251, 200, 
          200, 190, 317, 371, 351, 313, 367, 338, 356, 
          351, 335, 295, 250, 250, 200, 175, 150, 317,
          371, 351, 313, 289, 265, 298, 145, 278, 295,
          250, 250, 200, 125, 198)
)
```

and I'd like to know whether the correlation between `Yield` and `Index` changes for different `Variety`.
Here the plot of the data:

```
ggplot(Help_df, aes(x=Yield, y=Index, color=Variety)) +
 geom_point(shape=16, size=3) +
 geom_smooth(method=lm,   # Add linear regression lines
              se=FALSE)    # Don't add shaded confidence region
```

[image: I wander if these regression lines are different]

Reading this [help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66250/compare-2-regression-lines-in-r?rq=1) I've tested these two `Anova`:

```
   Anova(lm(Yield~Index*Variety,data=Help_df))
   Anova(lm(formula = Yield ~ Variety + Index + Variety:Index, data = Help_df))
```

As far as I know, the term `Index:Variety` indicates that the correlations have different slopes for different `Variety`. 
I'd like to know what is the difference between the two models, since the two `Anova` outputs are very similar, and if there is a kind of "post-hoc test" that indicates which `Variety` is different from the others (in this case is evident that `Mare` is totally different, but it's not always that easy to identify which factor differs).

Moreover I've tried the solution proposed by @PAC to use the "Chow test" as you can see in the link posted above. 
This test might be the best one, because it compares slopes+intercepts. But the p-value of 1 indicates that there is no difference of the correlation between `Yield` and `Index` for different `Variety` that is not consistent with what I can observe in the data.

```
mc  <- lm(formula = Index ~ YIELD, data = Help)
m1  <-  lm(formula = Index ~ YIELD, data = subset(Help, Variety == "'Augusto'"))
m2  <-  lm(formula = Index ~ YIELD, data = subset(Help, Variety == "'Sirio CL'"))
m3  <-  lm(formula = Index ~ YIELD, data = subset(Help, Variety == "'Mare CL'"))

sc  <- sum(mc$residuals^2)
s1  <- sum(m1$residuals^2)
s2  <- sum(m2$residuals^2)
s3  <- sum(m3$residuals^2)
k  <- 3
# Test statistic
fstat  <- (sc - (s1 + s2 + s3)) / k / (s1 + s2 + s3) * (length(mc$residuals) - 2*k)  
fstat

# Rejection region
qf(.95,k, length(mc$residuals) - 2*k)

# Pvalue
pf(fstat,k, length(mc$residuals) - 2*k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ANOVAs are not only similar, but identical. Read `help("formula")`.

For the pairwise comparisons I would do this:

```
m12  <-  lm(formula = Yield ~ Index, 
            data = subset(Help_df, Variety %in% c('Augusto', 'Sirio CL')))
m12v  <- lm(formula = Yield ~ Index * Variety, 
            data = subset(Help_df, Variety %in% c('Augusto', 'Sirio CL')))

m13 <- lm(formula = Yield ~ Index, 
          data = subset(Help_df, Variety %in% c('Augusto', 'Mare CL')))
m13v  <-  lm(formula = Yield ~ Index * Variety, 
             data = subset(Help_df, Variety %in% c('Augusto', 'Mare CL')))

m23  <-  lm(formula = Yield ~ Index, 
            data = subset(Help_df, Variety %in% c('Sirio CL', 'Mare CL')))
m23v  <-  lm(formula = Yield ~ Index * Variety, 
             data = subset(Help_df, Variety %in% c('Sirio CL', 'Mare CL')))

p.adjust(
  c(anova(m12, m12v)$"Pr(>F)"[2],
    anova(m13, m13v)$"Pr(>F)"[2],
    anova(m23, m23v)$"Pr(>F)"[2]),
  method = "holm")
#[1] 1.290727e-04 2.845623e-05 1.340764e-05
```